# Can I set up a debian nfs server and have a fedora nfs client?

Tags: linux, system-administration

Just wanted to make sure I could mix the two flavors of linux before I installed Fedora on my new laptop hard drive. I'm guessing that nfs is generic to all linux distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, NFS works across multiple operating systems, let alone versions of Linux. You do have to use the same protocol level on the two, however.

Comment: I didn't realize there were different protocols. I had it working between two Debian machines. This will be my first attempt with a different flavor.